# Date Format Confusion

Tags: java, date

in my App User Selects Date like `2013-01-02` 
   but in MySql DB the column format is like `02-Jan-2013` so want change the Date Format

my code is:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy");
    Date start_date = (Date)formatter.parse(GBRF.getStart_date());//GBRF.getStart_date() returns Form Data as 2013-01-02
    String dt=formatter1.format(start_date);
    Date sd=(Date)formatter1.parse(dt);
```

at the End `sd` print Date like this `Wed Jan 02 00:01:00 IST 2013`

i dont want that format..
just i want like `02-Jan-2013`

give me an idea..
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

You can format `Date` into `String` with `SimpleDateFormat`, after that if you try to print date instance it will invoke `toString()` method of Date class which has no change in output and you can't alter that output because it is coming from `toString()` implmentation

Note: in your format you need to use M for month (note capital M)

Answer (score 2):

A `Date` object does not have a format in itself. It holds just a point in time. The format comes into play when you convert it to or from a `String`.

Also note that `m` in the format is used for minutes not months. So you probably want a format like `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Try

```
System.out.println(formatter1.format(sd));
```

to get the date printed as you like it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your date format first :

```
`SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");`
```

In your case, if you just print `dt`, it should print date in the required format instead of converting it into `Date` object again i.e. `sd`

When you are printing `sd`, without any formatting it will print the default String implementation of Date object which is exactly what you are seeing as an output